# Android multiple ImageViews to use the same scale

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an image that is sliced into 3 parts (top `320x57`, middle `320x138`, bottom `320x233`).

How could I ensure that those 3 parts use the same scale, on every screen so that the final picture does not get distorted.

Here is my layout, with 3 corresponding ImageViews:

(Ignore the `AutoResizeTextView` - it's just my custom implementation of a `TextView`)

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:paddingTop="25dp"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            >
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/Top"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="top part"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:src="@drawable/tops" />
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/Middle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="middle part"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:src="@drawable/middles" />

  <AutoResizeTextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Middle"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Middle"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Middle"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Middle"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/Bottom"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="bottom part"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:src="@drawable/bottoms" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When every part of image (`top`, `middle`, `bottom`) fits the screen (no scaling) the final picture looks fine,
however on small screen only the bottom image is scaled and the other two are left untouched (or may be they are all scaled but unevenly).

Any ideas how could I achieve all 3 images use the same scale and fit any screen ?
Thanks.

**Note:**
I tried using `top` and `middle` imageView's `.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)` method to set same width and height that I got from inside of `bottom` imageView's
`onGlobalLayout()` - without noteworthy results.

Comment: You could wrap the layout in a _ScrollView_, but that may not be acceptable. Can you change the layout to _ConstraintLayout_? That may be a better option here. ` android:scaleType="matrix"` on the bottom view should get the width right, but may cut off the bottom of the image. If these don't work for you, then you may need to do some programmatic adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do what you want just using XML AFAIK. Given a total height for the three *ImageViews*, you will need to calculate a common width that will let each *ImageView* maintain the aspect ratio of its drawable.

You can get the aspect ratio of a drawable as follows:

```
val ratioTop = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.top_frame)!!.run {
    intrinsicWidth.toFloat() / intrinsicHeight
}
```

You can do the same to calculate the aspect ratios of the middle and bottom views.

Given the aspect ratios and the total height, calculate the new width (w) of all the *ImageViews* as follows:

> r is aspect ratio, w is width, h is height
> r1 = w1/h1, r2 = w2/h2, r3 = w3/h2, h = h1 + h2 + h2
> set w1, w2, w3 = w so h1 = w/r1, h2 = w/r2, h3 = w/r3
> w = h/(1/r1 + 1/r2 + 1/r3)

Given this common width for the *ImageViews*, calculate the new height as follows:

```
height = (w / ratioTop).toInt()
```

Do the same for the middle and bottom views. You will have to wait for an initial layout to get the value of `h`, so use a layout or global layout listener for this code.

Set the width and height of each view to the appropriate values and request a layout.

If you have padding/margins, you will need to make adjustments to accommodate them.